# How much is the number of reserved keys in Request.Params and Request.Forms in asp.net 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just want to Submit a Form using Web Request Object in ASP.Net C#. Here my problem is for advance checking that is there new request made from outer application.

here is my console application :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create web request object
            WebRequest objWebRequest;

            // Set url properties
            string url = "http://localhost:2055/EasyWeb/Admin/Post_History.aspx";
            objWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
            objWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            // add sample form data
            ArrayList queryList = new ArrayList();
            queryList.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", "title", "From Admin to All Users"));
            queryList.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", "desc", "hi all users"));
            queryList.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", "category", "Test"));
            queryList.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", "touser", null));
            queryList.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", "status", null));
            queryList.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", "group", null));
            queryList.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", "isfile", "False"));
            queryList.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", "sentdatetime", DateTime.Now.ToString()));
            // Set the encoding type
            objWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            string Parameters = String.Join("&", (String[])queryList.ToArray(typeof(string)));
            objWebRequest.ContentLength = Parameters.Length;

            // Write stream
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(objWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
            sw.Write(Parameters);
            sw.Close();

            //we get back the response after submission
            HttpWebResponse objHttpWebResponse;
            objHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objWebRequest.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my web application page load method.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Params.Keys.Count >54) // this line getting inconsistent no of value
        {
            using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
            {
                Session["Username"] = db.Users.Where(u => u.type_id.Equals("1")).Select(u => u.Username).FirstOrDefault();
                string title = null, desc = null, category = null, touser = null, status = null, group = null, isfile = null, sentdatetime = null;
                foreach (string strName in Request.Params)
                {
                    string strValue = Request.Form[strName];
                    switch (strName)
                    {
                        case "title":
                            title = strValue;
                            break;
                        case "desc":
                            desc = strValue;
                            break;
                        case "category":
                            category = strValue;
                            break;
                        case "touser":
                            touser = strValue;
                            break;
                        case "status":
                            status = strValue;
                            break;
                        case "group":
                            group = strValue;
                            break;
                        case "isfile":
                            isfile = strValue;
                            break;
                        case "sentdatetime":
                            sentdatetime = strValue;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                int category_id = db.Categories.Where(c => c.Category_name.Equals(category)).Select(c => c.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                int user_id = db.Users.Where(u => u.type_id.Equals("1")).Select(u => u.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                System.Nullable<int> touser_id = null;
                System.Nullable<int> status_id = null;
                System.Nullable<int> group_id = null;
                System.Nullable<DateTime> sent_datetime = null;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(touser))
                {
                    touser_id = db.Users.Where(u => (u.First_name + ' ' + u.Last_name).Equals(touser)).Select(u => u.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(status))
                {
                    status_id = db.Status.Where(s => s.status_name.Equals(status)).Select(s => s.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(group))
                {
                    group_id = db.Groups.Where(g => g.Group_name.Equals(group)).Select(g => g.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                }
                bool is_file = Convert.ToBoolean(isfile);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sentdatetime))
                {
                    sent_datetime = DateTime.Parse(sentdatetime);
                }
                Post myPost = new Post();
                myPost.Title = title;
                myPost.Category_id = category_id;
                myPost.Description = desc;
                myPost.User_id = user_id;
                myPost.ToUser_id = touser_id;
                myPost.status_id = status_id;
                myPost.group_id = group_id;
                myPost.IsFileAttached = is_file;
                myPost.Sent_Datetime = sent_datetime;
                db.Posts.InsertOnSubmit(myPost);
                db.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            var query = Helper.GetProfile().ToList();
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                GV_ViewPost.PageSize = item.Page_Size;
            }
            Panel_AddNew.Visible = false;
            Panel_View.Visible = false;
            Session["CommandName"] = "Inbox";
            Session["ColumnName"] = null;
            Session["SearchtText"] = null;
            this.FillGrid(Session["CommandName"].ToString(), (String)Session["ColumnName"] ?? null, (String)Session["SearchtText"] ?? null);
            Bind_DDL_Column_List();
            Bind_DDL_Category_List();
            Bind_Users_List();
            Bind_DDL_Group();
            Bind_DDL_Status();
        }
        this.GetData();
    }
```

here is this line `if (Request.Params.Keys.Count >54)` getting not fixed no of count of reserved (default) key.

By using this technique i have to check first new key found or not.

Is there anybody help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign some variables from values in `Request.Params`, simply do this:

```
string title = Request.Form["title"];
string desc = Request.Form["desc"];
...
```

You don't need to check if the parameter exits. If it's not then the variable will be null.

**Edit**: null check

```
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(title) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(desc) || ...)
{
    //Error: throw exception or: Response.Write("Please fill all needed parameters.")
    return;
}
```

Comment: And if variable null then i have got error can no insert null in to table value because i write submit statement for inserting values to database.

Comment: Then you can check for null and reject the request (send error as response).

Comment: you don't have i idea about no of default key from Response.Params

Comment: You don't need it at all (and you can't get it).

Comment: here can i go with continue label or simply drag (!Page.IsPostBack) portion to this brackets.

Answer (score 1):

simply use

```
   If Context.Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("keyvalue") Then
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("keyvalue").ToString) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString("keyvalue")) Then

        End If
        'or if need 
        If IsNumeric(Request.QueryString("keyvalue")) Then

        End If
    End If
```

that's all

converted in c#

```
if (Context.Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("keyvalue")) {

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("keyvalue").ToString) | string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString("keyvalue"))) {
}
//'or if need 

if (Information.IsNumeric(Request.QueryString("keyvalue"))) {
}
}
```

Comment: can u just convert to c#